# session not working as expected with mobile devices

Tags: php, session

Hi,

I have a site with 2 versions, one for the PC and one for the mobile. PC version goes like this mysite.org whereas mobile version goes mysite.org/mobile
So when a user visits the site from a mobile device it is automatically redirected to mysite.org/mobile through JS code. That works fine, however, I am offering my users the choice to see the PC version instead so I need a way to tell the browser to stop redirecting once the PC version button is pressed. This is what I did.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['redirect'] = true;

# Check whether the session should be unset.
if ($_GET['no_redirect'] == "true") {
   unset($_SESSION['redirect']);
}

# Check whether the session is set.
if (isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) {
 $redirect = <<<EOF
<script type='text/javascript'>DM_redirect("mobile/$page");</script>
EOF;
}
?>
```

my html code goes like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/mobile.js'></script>
  $redirect
```

if the $redirect variable is empty, redirection will not occur no matter what device is being used. The variable wont be empty as long as $_SESSION['redirect'] is true. So my button to stop redirecting and see the PC version looks like this:

```
<a href="&no_redirect=false" rel="alternate">SEE PC VERSION</a>
```

whereas the button to go back to the mobile version looks like this

```
<a href="&no_redirect=true" rel="alternate">SEE MOBILE VERSION</a>
```

it wont quite work because after pressing the PC version button it goes indeed to the PC version page but if I navigate from there it redirects again to the mobile version. What solution can I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are always setting `$_SESSION['redirect']` to `true`and only unsetting it when `$_GET['no_redirect']` is set. So your if condition is always true except for when the "PC version" button is pressed.
You could try the following code instead:

```
session_start();
// if we haven't set redirect, assume we want to redirect
if (!isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;

// Do we want to keep redirecting?
if ($_GET['no_redirect'] == "true") {
    $_SESSION['redirect'] = false;
}

// Should we redirect?
if ($_SESSION['redirect']) {
    $redirect = <<<EOF
<script type='text/javascript'>DM_redirect("mobile/$page");</script>
EOF;
}
```

This code will now only set `$_SESSION['redirect']` to `true` if it wasn't already set. However, that won't let you get back to the mobile version. Assuming that if the "Mobile version" button is pressed, the page will be called with `$_GET['no_redirect']` = `"false"`, in which case you can change the first part of the code to this:

```
session_start();
// if we haven't set redirect, assume we want to redirect
if (!isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;

// Do we want to keep redirecting?
if ($_GET['no_redirect'] == "true") {
    $_SESSION['redirect'] = false;
}
elseif ($_GET['no_redirect'] == "false") {
    $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;
}
```

Comment: You are right. I couldnt figure out how to get around that but your example works like a charm. Thank you.